# Probability :Knock Out Tournament Of Ranked Players

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

> Thirty-two players ranked 1 to 32 are playing in a knockout
>   tournament. Assume that in every match between any two players, the
>   better-ranked player wins, the probability that ranked 1 and ranked 2
>   players are winner and runner up respectively, is ?

I dont understand. Should'nt the player ranked 1 always be the winner as the better ranked guy always wins?

Comment: The player ranked $1$ will always win, but he might knock out the second-ranked player before the finals. You need the probability that the second-ranked player is in the other half of the draw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you picture the usual tree diagram for a [tournament bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(tournament)), you'll see that the 1 and 2 seeds will meet in the final if and only if they start on opposite sides of the bracket.  By symmetry, it doesn't matter where you position the 1 seed (so you may as well place her say at the top left).  This leaves $31$ possible starting positions for the 2 seed, $16$ of which are on the opposite side from the 1 seed.  So the probability they'll meet in the final (where the 1 seed will prevail) is

$${16\over31}\approx.516129$$

Comment: Excellent....and well explained answer.Thanks for the diagram mainly.It cleared many of my doubts! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the player ranked number $1$ will win all of his matches, and will eventually win the tournament.

But you are asked what the probability is that the players ranked $1$ and $2$ will meet in the final (because only in this scenario, the ranked $1$ player will win, and the ranked $2$ player will be the runner-up).

For the two players to meet in the final, you need to avoid that they meet before the final, and this is what you need to find the probability of.

Answer (score 1):

The top ranked player will always win, but the second ranked player will only reach the finals if he doesn't play the top ranked player in the first 4 games. In a knockout tournament with a bracket that means that they must be on opposite halves of the bracket, but in a tournament without a set bracket you are looking for the probability that the player ranked second doesn't play the player ranked first in each round.

$R_{1} * R_{2} * R_{3} * R_{4}$, where $R_{n}$ is the probability of surviving each round, or:

$\frac{30\text{ wins}}{31\text{ possible opponents}} * \frac{14}{15} * \frac{6}{7} * \frac{2}{3} = 0.516129$

Comment: If you don't have a set bracket, presumably the second ranked player is guaranteed to reach the final, as you will always make sure he doesn't play the first ranked.  I don't understand your calculation.

Comment: If there is no set bracket, games are determined each round. In the first round, the second ranked player has a $\frac{1}{31}$ chance of playing the number one ranked player. Therefore, he has a $\frac{30}{31}$ chance of making it to the next round. This applies to the next two rounds as well. Assuming he makes the fourth round, he has an equal chance to play 3 different people, and he can beat 2 of them, which advances him to the final round (which he cannot win).

Comment: I think you mean $0.516129$, not $0.5269$ (see my answer, which offers an alternate derivation).

Comment: I don't see why such a complex computation (which also seems to be incorrect) is needed. If the draws are random, all that we need to ensure is that the $2nd$ ranked player is not in the same half as the $1st$ ranked one.

Comment: Oh, I see that your complex approach is correct, please correct the numerical result.

Comment: If the games are determined at random each round, you might as well have a set bracket that reflects the determination.  It doesn't matter.

Comment: @trueblueanil, I initially thought (in part because the numerical answers seemed to differ) that randomly reseeding after each round would give a different answer than simply sticking with a fixed, random seeding.  It was only when I saw the answers are actually the same that I realized reseeding doesn't matter.  (Oh, funny, I was writing this while Ross Millikan was posting!)

Comment: @BarryCipra: Yea, I didn't examine the approach at all, because the answer was apparently wrong !

Comment: @BarryCipra Yeah, we were calculating different solutions. The wording of the initial question wasn't entirely clear, but I alluded to your solution in my introduction. I ended up calculating what was basically "Swiss" parings based on how I read the question. Nice answer and discussion though.

Comment: @Fritz, but your final decimal answer is wrong.  I'm not sure how you obtained it, but it should be $0.516129$, not $0.5269$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Ohhh... I see what you're saying now. I typed it in again an i'm getting your answer. I must have had a typo when I first calculated it.

Comment: @Fritz, no problem.  I tried to figure out what the typo might have been to produce the number you got, but couldn't pinpoint it.

Comment: @Fritz Sir is it possible to do this problem too with the without bracket one ? As i was consideeing to solve using that approach : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2091350/922054

Answer (score 1):

The only way the $2nd$ ranked player is not runner up is if the draws are randomly put.

The $1st$ ranked player can be anywhere, and will win
The $2nd$ ranked player, however, *must* be in the other half to be runner up,
hence $Pr = \dfrac{16}{31}$